# Now that I think about it, my questions should be in the Linux stack Exchange

Tags: support

I've been working on a Raspberry Pi project over the weekend, and I posted some questions here.  Eventually, after rereading the question criteria for this stack exchange, I realized that the questions should probably be over in the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Can someone move them for me please? I don't think I have sufficient privileges or access.

[Raspbian/Octopi and the TL-WN725N v1 wifi adapter; drivers included?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34487/raspbian-octopi-and-the-tl-wn725n-v1-wifi-adapter-drivers-included)

[Octopi.local does not resolve - DNS name resolution issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34517/octopi-local-does-not-resolve-dns-name-resolution-issue)

Comment: Beware that migrated questions retain their timestamps, and since U&L is much busier, moving something that's 15+ hours old will put it a day back in the "new" queue.   If you want, I can close both of those as off-topic, then you can cut and paste them.

Answer (score 6):

The general rule is not to migrate questions with answers. So your first question should not be migrated. The second has no answers so you can simply delete it and post it on U&L yourself.